# Как загрузить и вывести картинку используя WinApi?

Tags: c++, winapi

Объясните, как загрузить и вывести битмап?

Также насколько я понял не все bmp картинки подходят, какие есть для них требования?

Comment: Найдите на msdn разделы про GDI/GDI+ и WIC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вариант 1 - GDI

```
// загрузка bitmap-а из файла:
HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\файл.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
// создание memory DC для этого bitmap-а:                   
HDC bmpDC = CreateCompatibleDC(wndDC);
SelectObject(bmpDC, hBmp);
// вывод (wndDC - HDC окна):
BitBlt(wndDC, 0, 0, width, height, bmpDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
// освобождение ресурсов:           
DeleteDC(bmpDC);
DeleteObject(hBmp);
```

### Вариант 2 - GDI+

Заголовочный файл и пространство имён:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
```

Ещё нужно прилинковать библиотеку импорта `gdiplus.lib`. В Visual Studio для этого можно использовать директиву:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
```

GDI+ требует предварительной инициализации, при запуске приложения нужно выполнить:

```
ULONG_PTR gdiToken;
GdiplusStartupInput gdiInput;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiToken, &gdiInput, NULL);
```

А при завершении приложения:

```
GdiplusShutdown(gdiToken);
```

Загрузка и вывод bitmap-а:

```
Graphics graphics(wndDC); //wndDC - HDC окна
Bitmap bmp(L"C:\\файл.bmp");
graphics.DrawImage(&bmp, 0, 0, width, height);
```

### Вариант 3 - Direct2D

Рекомендуемый Microsoft (GDI и GDI+ объявлены устаревшими), но самый неудобный вариант - требуется писать слишком много кода, для такой простой задачи (поэтому писать его здесь я не буду). На MSDN есть примеры:

[Creating a Simple Direct2D Application](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-quickstart)

[How to Load a Bitmap from a File](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-load-a-direct2d-bitmap-from-a-file)

[How to Draw a Bitmap](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-draw-a-bitmap)